# How to extract attachments from EML files with Windows command line?

Tags: command-line, email, batch

I have hundreds of EML files which are single emails with attachments.

I would like to use scripting to get the attachments, that's why I'm looking for a way to extract any attachment from a single EML file in a command line.

I could parse each file to look for the attachment and use a base64 decoder on that, but I hope that someone has already written this.

Any recommendation?

Comment: Tool requests are considered off-topic: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5845/are-tool-requests-on-topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try use:

1. [mpack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpack-win/)(Windows version of *mpack/munpack* using the version 1.6 source obtained from http://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/mpack/).
2. [B64Dec tool](http://4mhz.de/b64dec.html)(command line supports).

Comment: Just would like to chip in that `munpack` works great for Unix enviroments.

Comment: `munpack` tells me `Did not find anything to unpack` for a `.eml` that contains 2 attachments.

Comment: In my case munpack doesn't recognize base64 encoding, `munpack: warning: ignoring unknown content transfer encoding`

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a plug, https://bitbucket.org/mookins/email-extractor
It take input of .eml files in a directory, then it will iterate over these and output them to a destination folder.

It runs on Java.

Comment: Hey @mookins What happened to this java library? This response was edited in 2017, but the repository seems to have gone offline since that time.